# Website won't reach with a certain domain

Tags: nameserver

I have a website named persianboneh.com , it is unreachable, but with another domain parked on this domain it works ok.
persianboneh.com
soulati.ir
both have same name servers , what is the problem ?

Comment: Hint: `persianboneh.com` has no A record; `soulati.ir` does.

Comment: This is not true:

dig @ns1.radicalteam.ir persianboneh.com

returns the correct (same as soulati.ir) IP which is 185.94.97.188

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Found it. You have wrong NS Records in your name server's zone.

Wrong:

```
ns1.radicalteram.ir.
ns2.radicalteram.ir.
```

Correct:

```
ns1.radicalteam.ir.
ns2.radicalteam.ir.
```

Fix this issue wait a few hours (depending on your TTL) and i am pretty sure your problem will be solved.

Comment: Nice catch; +1 from me, even though I think it's a poor question.